# ¿Cómo se separan los diferentes elementos de un SELECT COUNT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta SQL que me dice cuantos personas se han connectados al menos una vez el dia pasado y me gustaría hacer una consulta para saber cuantos personas se han conectado al menos una vez durante el año pasado para cada lenguaje (`Lang`).

Por ejemplo con este schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`App Type` varchar(11), `Lang` varchar(2), `Session ID` int, `session_time` datetime, `User ID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO sessions
    (`App Type`, `Lang`, `Session ID`, `session_time`, `User ID`)
VALUES
    #july 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1193745),
    # june 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 12345),
    # june 2020
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 54321)

;
```

Puedo saber cada día cuántas personas se conectan al menos el año pasado gracias a:

```
SELECT sessions.session_time, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`)) 
  FROM sessions s2 
  WHERE s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sessions.session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND sessions.session_time
)
FROM sessions
GROUP BY sessions.session_time
```

Que pueden probar en [este Fiddle enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19c58/22/0).

Pero cómo puedo hacerlo para obtener los mismos resultados para cada Lenguaje? Hasta hoy intenté:

```
SELECT sessions.session_time, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`)) 
  FROM sessions s2 
  WHERE s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sessions.session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND sessions.session_time
)
FROM sessions
GROUP BY sessions.session_time, sessions.Lang
```

Utilizo MySQL 5.7

## Con la respuesta de A. Cedano

Lo he adaptado para intentar obtener el número de personas por idioma que se han conectado al menos una vez en el último año :

```
 SELECT 
    DATE(session_time),
    Lang,
    COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM sessions 
    WHERE YEAR(session_time) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
 GROUP BY Lang, DATE(session_time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres contar la cantidad de usuarios por lenguaje durante el año pasado, con esta consulta bastaría:

```
 SELECT 
    `User ID`, 
    COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM sessions 
    WHERE YEAR(session_time) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
 GROUP BY  Lang, `User ID`
```

No tienes por qué liarte con sub-consultas ni con DISTINCT ...

Si quieres que agrupe también por cada día, sólo tienes que agregar la parte de la fecha de `session_time` en el `GROUP BY` usando `DATE`, eso agrupará los registros sin tomar en cuenta la hora:

```
 SELECT 
    `User ID`, 
    COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM sessions 
    WHERE YEAR(session_time) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
 GROUP BY  Lang, `User ID`, DATE(session_time)
```

Comment: Sí, eso es exactamente, pero quiero hacerlo para cada día mirando hacia atrás un año

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica si te interesa un resultado por días solamente tienes que agregar la columna `session_time` al `GROUP BY`, dado que dicha columna es de tipo `DATETIME` agrupas solamente por la fecha, sin tener en cuenta la hora.

Comment: Es decir, agregarías `DATE(session_time)` en la parte del  `GROUP BY`

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué mantiene el ID de usuario en su SELECT cuando quiere contar el número de usuarios por idioma que se han conectado al menos una vez en el último año?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica mantengo el ID del usuario porque supuse que querías ver al lado de cada total qué usuario es, si esa info no interesa lo puedes quitar del SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Si en el `select` principal agregas Lang, tu consulta te dirá en qué idioma se inició sesión y cúantas veces

```
SELECT sessions.session_time, `Lang`, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`))
  FROM sessions s2 
  WHERE s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sessions.session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND sessions.session_time
)
FROM sessions
GROUP BY sessions.session_time, sessions.Lang
```

---

Edito:
utilizando la cláusula `with`

```
with sesiones as(
  select session_time, Lang,
    USER_ID
  from sessions s2
  WHERE s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND session_time
)
 SELECT 
    session_time,
    lang,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(User_ID)) 
 FROM sesiones 
 GROUP BY  Lang
```

con ese ejemplo que te dejo, me funciona con los datos que habias dejado anteriormente, sería cuestión de que pruebes si te funciona con la gran cantidad de datos que manejas en la BD

Comment: Muchas gracias Jésus! Sin embargo con los datos reales la solicitud tarda mucho tiempo (ni siquiera tiene éxito) Efectivamente, tengo 37 millones de filas en una tabla, ¿crees que todavía se puede hacer con SQL?

Comment: si tienes esa cantidad de datos creo que podrías utilizar la cláusula WITH que va creando tablas temporales y generalmente en consulta con un volumen alto de datos no tarda demasiado en dar la respuesta

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¿Y cómo adaptaría tu consulta con estos CON para poder manejar todas estas líneas?

Comment: acabo de editar la respuesta, el ejemplo funciona con los pocos datos que dejaste en tu ejemplo, tendrías que adaptarlo a tu consulta para saber si realmente te funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias, mi compilador me dice que hay un error de sintaxis pero lo encontraré y lo arreglaré

Comment: si es que cambie los nombres de las columnas, coloque user_id

Comment: Parece que el error tiene más que ver con el WITH, porque la subconsulta funciona bien como se muestra en [este Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/930af3/3/0) pero la parte comentada tiene errores

Comment: si estoy viendo que el problema es la versión de MySQL, que anterior a la 8.0 no soporta la cláusula WITH, si mi respuesta no te ayuda lo mejor es que quites el aceptado de ella :D!

Comment: Raaah, es una pena porque el primero código es bueno pero en 37 millones de líneas no es aplicable RRRrrrr

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica si 37 millones de filas te generan problemas, deberias revisar los indices de tu tabla....